# conda install pyspark 2.3.1 InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7

Tags: python, pyspark, conda

I am trying to install `pyspark` to my virtual environment on a Linux box. Following code was used and it was previously working fine. All of sudden we are facing an issue.

```bash
conda install -q -y -c conda-forge pyspark==2.3.1
```

During the above step, my installation fails with the error message:

```bash
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(148): verbosity set to 2
Solving environment: ...working... DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(142): solving prefix /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/envs/utilization_venv
  specs_to_remove: frozenset()
  specs_to_add: frozenset({MatchSpec(name=LowerStrMatch('pyspark'), version=VersionSpec('2.3.1.*'))})
  prune: False
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(237): package cache directory '/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(237): package cache directory '/home/olgaci/.conda/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/d77296e0.json. Timeout in 25 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/d77296e0.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json. Timeout in 25 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64 at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/7b043413.json. Timeout in 23 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/7b043413.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64 at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/47929eba.json. Timeout in 23 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/47929eba.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/5fa16146.json. Timeout in 23 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/5fa16146.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.json. Timeout in 251 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64 at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.json. Timeout in 22 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64 at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/98cb6fa3.json. Timeout in 22 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/98cb6fa3.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64 at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/497deca9.json. Timeout in 264 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/497deca9.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(216): Using cached repodata for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch at /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json. Timeout in 20 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(293): found pickle file /***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.q
failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
    force_reinstall=context.force,
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 518, in solve_for_transaction
    force_remove, force_reinstall)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 451, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 180, in solve_final_state
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 592, in _prepare
    self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 217, in get_reduced_index
    push_record(record)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 198, in push_record
    for _spec in record.combined_depends:
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/records.py", line 273, in combined_depends
    result = {ms.name: ms for ms in MatchSpec.merge(self.depends)}
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 411, in merge
    match_specs = tuple(cls(s) for s in match_specs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 411, in <genexpr>
    match_specs = tuple(cls(s) for s in match_specs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(MatchSpecType, cls).__call__(**parsed)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._match_components = self._build_components(**kwargs)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 367, in _build_components
    return frozendict(_make(key, value) for key, value in iteritems(kwargs))
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 367, in <genexpr>
    return frozendict(_make(key, value) for key, value in iteritems(kwargs))
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 361, in _make
    matcher = _implementors[field_name](value)
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py", line 429, in __new__
    self.tup = tup = tuple(VersionSpec(s) for s in spec[1:])
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py", line 429, in <genexpr>
    self.tup = tup = tuple(VersionSpec(s) for s in spec[1:])
  File "/***jenkins/workspace/utilization-build-branch-pipeline/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py", line 445, in __new__
    raise InvalidVersionSpecError(spec)
conda.exceptions.InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7
```

Kindly help.

```
 Conda Info 
**********

     active environment : utilization_venv
    active env location : ***/jenkins/workspace/branch-pipeline/miniconda/envs/utilization_venv
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/olgaci/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : ***/jenkins/workspace/branch-pipeline/miniconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : ***/jenkins/workspace/branch-pipeline/miniconda/pkgs
                          /home/olgaci/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : ***/jenkins/workspace/branch-pipeline/miniconda/envs
                          /home/olgaci/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.12 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Linux/3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 rhel/7.9 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 27650:26686
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

Solving environment: ...working... done
```

This is the list of packages am trying to install.

```
conda install -y -q bokeh==1.0.0 flask arrow==0.12.1 PyYAML==3.12 cryptography==2.2.2

--if os type is linux
conda install -y -q flask-cors gunicorn

conda install -q -c conda-forge -y findspark
conda install -y -q pytest coverage pytest-cov snakeviz nose=1.3.7 flake8==3.7.9 ipython future

conda install -y -c conda-forge -q lapack==3.6.1 cvxopt==1.2.0

conda install -q -y numpy==1.14.3
conda install -q -y scipy==1.1.0
conda install -q -y ecos==2.0.5
conda install -q -y -c cvxgrp cvxpy==1.0.6

conda install -q -y -c conda-forge pyspark==2.3.1

conda install -q -y -c anaconda mysql-connector-python==8.0.13
```

The problem comes when it tries to install pyspark. When i tried to install pyspark first followed by other packages am facing unsatisfiable error for numpy and scipy. Need help

Comment: @merv but i see all my other packages are using double = convention and they work perfectly fine. let me run in non-quite mode as you suggested. and will post the results.

Comment: @merv i have added the error report in this stack kindly help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819039/conda-install-invalidversionspecerror-invalid-version-spec-2-7

Comment: @merv added conda info to the post. kindly help.

Comment: It appears your Conda version is still outdated (`conda update -n base conda`); that should be updated, as Romain suggested.

Comment: @merv am worried if i update conda. i need to update all other packages which is installed. Will it really help updating conda and not updating other installed packages?

Comment: @merv tried updating conda version as said above. Now none of my packages are getting installed. Before pyspark was failing and now all the packages are failing.

Comment: if you have new information to add, then please update the question. You have only ever mentioned needing to install one package prior to this. Are you installing a set of packages? Are you installing them at once, or in a sequence of commands?

Comment: @merv as suggested added the list of installation sequence to the post. Kindly help.

Comment: @merv I have added the sequence of installation. Please help

Comment: @Romain if you find anything out of this installation sequence please let me know.

Comment: Please rework to install from a YAML or a requirements.txt - a series of `conda install` commands like this is wasteful, sensitive to order of commands, and (evidently) unmaintainable. Also, is the error still the same? If not, that needs to be updated.

Comment: Yes, merv the error is still the same. If i reorder my pyspark installation it works fine and it fails during numpy installation.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it with the same command in a fresh `3.7` environment. I think you should check your version of `conda` and use a more recent one (`4.9.2` is the latest available).

```sh
conda --version
# conda 4.9.2
```

For existing environment you could try to [clean](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html) the cache since I see in the logs that conda is using an index cache that may contain incorrect information.

```sh
# clean just the index as suggested my @merv
conda clean --index-cache
# clean all the cache if needed
conda clean --all
```

You can also choose to create a new fresh environment dedicated to pyspark, here is an example.

```sh
# create a new env
conda create -y -n pyspark pyspark=2.3.1

# activate it
conda activate pyspark

# check if pyspark is installed
conda list pyspark
# packages in environment at /opt/conda/envs/pyspark:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
# pyspark                   2.3.1                 py37_1001    conda-forge
```

Comment: Thank you, will check. Yes am aware that pyspark 2.3.1 is an older version. other versions are old and compatible with 2.3.1

Comment: Tried installing latest conda and still facing issue @Romain

Comment: @saravan sorry, I've updated my answer to suggest to clean the cache because I've seen in the logs that the solver is using the index cache.

Comment: Why not specifically `conda clean --index-cache`? What does additionally deleting tarballs and packages benefit the user?

Comment: @merv My idea was to clean the cache and you're right cleaning the index could be enough since the error lays more probably in the index. I will update my answer thanks.

Comment: @Romain I tried to add the conda clean code before pyspark installation code. Still am facing the same issue. And if i install newer conda version, then i must replace all other packages to newer version which is a challenge.